# django forms не проходит валидацию

Tags: django

После переопределения **init** в форме ProjectForm валидация данных не проходит, ошибок нет.

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.user = user

class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = ['colour', 'name']
    widgets = {
        'colour': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'color'}),
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'project name', 'autofocus': 'autofocus'})
    }
```

Так же, замечу, что в TaskForm аналогичное переопределение **init**, но проблем не возникло.

Comment: Лучше не добавлять лишних аргументов в __init__, тк неизвестно, как он дальше используется в дебрях фреймворка. Лучше используйте kwargs

Comment: `self.user = kwargs.pop('user' , None)`

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, согласен с Вами!

Answer (score 0):

По какой-то причине форма во views больше не принимает request.POST позиционно, нужно передавать именованно data=request.POST

Comment: А views при этом вы так и не показали